# Get the results into a session variable causing __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object

Tags: php, filemaker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Session, PHP Incomplete Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069120/session-php-incomplete-class)

Need some help please. I've got the following code, which queries the FileMaker database in PHP.

The query brings up the expected results, and as I want to use those results elsewhere I want to store/cache them in a session. However When I store them in a `$_SESSION`, I get  `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` Object, but if I print the normal result, it seems to print fine.

This is the code that works and below which doesn't. They are amost identical. Im using FileMakers own PHP installation. PHP 5

**Working Code:**

```
if(!session_id()) session_start();

$find = $fm->newFindCommand('Web'); 

$find->addFindCriterion('ID', '=='.$_SESSION['ID']);

$Results = $find->execute();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($Results); // this prints perfectly i.e. FileMaker_Result_Implementation Object
echo "</pre>";
```

**Broken Code:**

```
if(!session_id()) session_start();

$find = $fm->newFindCommand('Web'); 

$find->addFindCriterion('ID', '=='.$_SESSION['ID']);

$Results = $find->execute();

$_SESSION['results'] = $Results;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION); //I want to print all the sessions out
echo "</pre>"
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__PHP_Incomplete_Class` means the class is unknown to PHP. Load the class before you start the session and everything should work

Comment: Hi Fabian, thanks for responding. Do you mean using the FileMaker.php class? I've already got require_once('FileMaker.php'); Still producing the same error.

Comment: I don't know FileMaker :) ... when you initializes the session, PHP tries to wake all the objects that are saved. But PHP need to parse a class Classname {} statement for all classes. http://adamyoung.net/PHP-Autoload-Hints